# Python looping through files and saving content to dict

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
import os
import json
import ipaddress

iplist = []
ipiflist = []
mydict = {}

for filename in os.listdir('data/'):
    with open(os.path.join('data/', filename), 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        mydict.update(data)
        print(mydict)
```

In the data directory there are several JSON files that I open in this loop.

I update the dict in every loop and for this reason I get the following output:

```
{'ipif_1001': '10.10.160.129', 'ipif_1002': '10.10.160.142', 'ipif_1003': '10.10.160.169', 'ipif_1004': '10.10.160.173', 'ipif_3334': '10.10.160.194', 'IpIf3337': '10.10.160.126'}
{'ipif_1001': '10.10.160.129', 'ipif_1002': '10.10.160.142', 'ipif_1003': '10.10.160.170', 'ipif_1004': '10.10.160.174', 'ipif_3334': '10.10.160.194', 'IpIf3337': '10.10.160.126', 'ipif_1005': '10.10.160.178', 'ipif_1006': '10.10.160.182'}
{'ipif_1001': '10.10.160.129', 'ipif_1002': '10.10.160.142', 'ipif_1003': '10.10.160.170', 'ipif_1004': '10.10.160.174', 'ipif_3334': '10.10.160.194', 'IpIf3337': '10.10.160.126', 'ipif_1005': '10.10.160.178', 'ipif_1006': '10.10.160.182', 'IpIf1001': '10.10.160.138', 'IpIf1002': '10.10.160.141', 'IpIf1003': '10.10.160.153', 'IpIf1006': '10.10.160.181', 'IpIf_CPEDCN': '10.10.160.241', 'IpIf_DCNMgt': '10.10.191.253', 'ipif1164': '10.10.160.166', 'IpIf1010': '10.10.170.1'}
```

I only need the summarized output from the last loop. How can I only access this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So, what is the expected output?

Comment: I think he means he only wants the last line of code he outputted - just take the `print(mydict)` outside of the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop in python has an *else* statement, which will only be executed when the loop was successful. Thus there you can plot your last resut?

```
for filename in os.listdir('data/'):
    with open(os.path.join('data/', filename), 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        mydict.update(data)
else:
    print(mydict)
```

Comment: i just noticed that this removes duplicate keys in the dict
is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: keys in dictionaries are always unique. (you can't have 2 keys with the same name | object in a dictionary).     A possible solution would be, is storing your values into a list. like:
**mydict.setdefault('code', []).append(ip_address)**
but then you've to run over the json **for code, ip_address in data.items():**

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import json
import ipaddress

iplist = []
ipiflist = []
mydict = {}
list = os.listdir('data/')

for filename in os.listdir('data/'):
    with open(os.path.join('data/', filename), 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        if list[list.count-1] == filename: #check last filename in the directory with the current filename in the loop
            mydict.update(data)
        print(mydict)
```

Try it like this